# Data not being stored in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to run this code on a NodeJS server and make 'POST' requests from Postman. I keep getting a response that turns up an empty `data` field when it should be populated with data.

This is the response from the server after a 'POST' request:

```
{
  data: []
}
```

The `data` array should not be empty.

```
var deviceModel = new Schema({
    data: [ { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true} ],
    time: { type: Date, default:Date.now }
});
```

This is the content of the main application file:

```
var app  = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//app.use(bodyParser.json());
var deviceData = mongoose.model('device1', deviceModel);
app.post('/',function(req, res){
  var devicedataat = new deviceData(req.body);
  console.log(req.body);
  devicedataat.save();

  console.log(devicedataat);
  res.status(201);
  res.send(devicedataat);
});
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application uses the `bodyParser.urlencoded` middleware so you'll need to send your data as `x-www-form-urlencoded` via Postman.

To send an array in the 'POST' request, you'll need to send each item. You can see an example below:

[image]

Comment: It is giving error saying TypeError: deviceModel.populate is not a function

Comment: That was a horrible error. The `.populate` method is to be called on a model and not a schema. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I am still getting the same response with empty data { data: [],
  time: Sun Jan 24 2016 22:35:56 GMT+0530 (IST),
  _id: 56a504745740b29f0355ecc9 }

Comment: My earlier solution made the assumption you used the '.post' method to view the responses. I've edited based on the assumption that you've defined a '.get' method.

Comment: I am using POST method only to view the responses, and data array is something I am sending as a whole like this {
    data: [400, 500, 123]
} by using Postman

Comment: I tested it out and discovered the problem. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
devicedataat.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  else console.log(devicedataat);
});
```

Save method should be used with a callback as it is asynchronous.

Comment: still facing the same issue

Comment: can you post your full source code here? full express file would be nice.

Comment: Its pretty much all of it